# HTTP 500 error with html / php form

Tags: php, forms

So I have the following codes:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="post.php">
<table width="597" class="formatTblClass">
<tr>
<th colspan="4"></th>
</tr>
<tr><input type="hidden" name="filename" value="example" /></tr>
<tr>
<td width="99"><span>First Name</span></td>
<td width="217"><input class="" type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /></td>
<td width="99"><span>Last Name</span></td>
<td width="211"><input class="" name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" /></td>
<td width="99"><span>Street Address</span></td>
<td width="217"><input class="" type="text" name="streetaddress" id="streetaddress" /></td>
<td width="99"><span>City</span></td>
<td width="211"><input class="" name="city" type="text" id="city" /></td>
<td width="99"><span>State</span></td>
<td width="211"><input class="" name="state" type="text" id="state" /></td>
<td width="99"><span>Phone Number</span></td>
<td width="211"><input class="" name="phone" type="text" id="phone" /></td>
<td width="99"><span>Email</span></td>
<td width="211"><input class="" name="email" type="text" id="email" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="4">Would you like to receive updates from Company?</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input id="optincompany" name="optincompany" type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="yes" />I want to receive updates from Company.<br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4">Would you like to receive updates from Dealer?</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="4"><input id="optindealer" name="optindealer" type="checkbox" checked="yes" value="yes" />I want to receive updates from Dealer.<br /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="4">
  <div align="center">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
  <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

post.php

```
<?php 

$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
$streetaddress = $_POST['streetaddress']; 
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$state = $_POST['state']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
//$optindealer = $_POST['optindealer']; 
//$optincompany = $_POST['optincompany']; 

$optindealer = ( strtolower($_POST['optindealer']) === 'yes' ) ? 'Y' : 'N'; 
$optincompany = ( strtolower($_POST['optincompany']) === 'yes' ) ? 'Y' : 'N'; 



$filename = $_POST['filename'] . ".csv"; 

$today = date("YmdHis");  


  $fp = fopen($filename, “a”); 

    $savestring = " " . "," . $today . "," . " " . "," . $firstname . “,” . $lastname . "," . "I" . $address . "," . $city . "," . $state . "," . $optindealer . "," . $today . "," . $phone . "," . $today . "," . $email . “,” . $optincompany . "," . $today; 
        echo $savestring; 
   fwrite($fp, $savestring); 
    fclose($fp); 



?>
```

Whenever I try to submit the form, I get a 500 Internal Server error (`HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`) And I can't quite figure out why. As far as I know, my php is well formed, and I (in desperation) have chmod'd the directory to 777 (which I will change as soon as I figure out what's going on here). Any advice?

Comment: Change all your `“ ”` to `"` that's the reason. They're known as fancy quotes and will surely put a dent in your code. Do that and try again.

Comment: Right, change: `$fp = fopen($filename, “a”);`  to `$fp = fopen($filename, "a");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change all your `“` and  `”` to `"` that's the reason it's giving you that [**`500`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) Internal Server error.

They're known as fancy quotes and should not be used in code execution.

**aka:**

- smart quotes
- curly quotes

You can do a search & replace in your favorite editor for these characters.

Here is an interesting article on the subject:

- **http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/stupid-quotes**

And a snippet to convert them to regular quotes, if needed:

- [Convert Smart Quotes back to normal](http://snippets.jc21.com/snippets/php/convert-smart-quotes-back-to-normal/)

Code pulled, should the link ever cease to exist:

```
<?php
function convert_smart_quotes($string) {
    //converts smart quotes to normal quotes.
    $search = array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(151));
    $replace = array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-');
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
}
?>
```

---

Rewrite:

```
<?php 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
$streetaddress = $_POST['streetaddress']; 
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$state = $_POST['state']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
//$optindealer = $_POST['optindealer']; 
//$optincompany = $_POST['optincompany']; 

$optindealer = ( strtolower($_POST['optindealer']) === 'yes' ) ? 'Y' : 'N'; 
$optincompany = ( strtolower($_POST['optincompany']) === 'yes' ) ? 'Y' : 'N'; 

$filename = $_POST['filename'] . ".csv"; 

$today = date("YmdHis");  

  $fp = fopen($filename, "a"); 

    $savestring = " " . "," . $today . "," . " " . "," . $firstname . "," . $lastname . "," . "I" . $address . "," . $city . "," . $state . "," . $optindealer . "," . $today . "," . $phone . "," . $today . "," . $email . "," . $optincompany . "," . $today; 
        echo $savestring; 
   fwrite($fp, $savestring); 
    fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax error on this line:

```
    $savestring = " " . "," . $today . "," . " " . "," . $firstname . “,” . $lastname . "," . "I" . $address . "," . $city . "," . $state . "," . $optindealer . "," . $today . "," . $phone . "," . $today . "," . $email . “,” . $optincompany . "," . $today;
```

You cant use `“`, use normal `"`...

Also here: `$fp = fopen($filename, “a”);`